# Local storage not retaining values

Tags: javascript, logging, local-storage

I am using `local storage` to save a few string values, in my web application when I login a different user, it replaces the data for other user.

I'll explain my problem by an example. Let's say there are two users A and B. `Local storage` key for A is `Alog` and `Blog` for B. So if B logins then `Alog` will be replaced by `Blog`. Whereas I want to retain both of them.

```
localStorage.setItem(user_logs, logs);
logs=localStorage.getItem(user_logs);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your codes please? It will be much easier to help

Comment: @KienHaTrung, I have edited my answer again so that you may understand. Complete code can not be uploaded here as it is too big. I have tried sharing problematic part of code.

Comment: What is your `user_logs`? Is it a variable? a string? Also `logs`, has it been stringified? Could you just share the code where you set these variables please?

Answer (score 0):

If it is overwriting, it is likely that the key `user_logs` is the same value. If otherwise, please provide where the variable is being set.

A better way to do it might be the following:

```
const userLogs = {
    userA: { ... },
};

localStorage.setItem("userLogs", JSON.stringify(userLogs));
```

To retrieve and edit:

```
const userLogs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userLogs");
userLogs.userB = { ... };

localStorage.setItem("userLogs", JSON.stringify(userLogs));
```

Comment: Both key and there value are different. In dashboard page, I set variable like `localStorage.setItem(user_logs, logs);`. For instance, I set logs for user A on dashboard page. When I login again from login page, it only retains `localstorage` varibles that are set in login page. Those set in dashboard page are discarded.

Comment: What is the value of the userLogs variable? It should be working the way you've described it if you are able to provide some code snippets myself/others would be able to better help you :)